# How long will the long-term survivors into old generation tenured？

Tags: java, jvm

I know long-term survivors will into old generation tenured when the Age is greater than MaxTenuringThreshold.But one book I read says,is also when the size of all objects of the same age in a Survivor space is greater than half of a Survivor space.So the problem is this Survivor space is SO or S0 + S1? Why not Eden + S0 or S1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram is a little off - the Permanent Generation doesn't exist in the heap, but rather in the non-heap space:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/presenting-the-permanent-generation

To answer your question, the young generation is made up of:

- Eden
- S0 + S1 (collectively known as Survivor Space).

There is a level of 'promotion' of objects within the heap like this: 
`

> Eden -> S0 -> S1 -> Old Generation (or tenured).

New Java objects are created in Eden, which has a fixed allocated size. Naturally, there will come a time when Eden is full, and a round of minor GC takes place. Still-referenced objects will be promoted into survivor space. As each minor GC occurs, the objects will be swap around S0 and S1.

Based on the number of times of GC that object has survived, it will eventually get promoted into Old Generation. Of course, there will also come a time when the old generation space will be full. A major GC will then be conducted to clean unreferenced objects up.

Give this a read:
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: Actually, it’s the old HotSpot JVM implementations which were off when disregarding the PermGen as part of the heap. The Java Virtual Machine Specification always specified, e.g in [JVMS11, §2.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3), “The heap is the run-time data area from which memory for all class instances and arrays is allocated”, therefore, since the PermGen contained objects, it must considered to be part of the heap, at least the parts of it containing objects. Thankfully, the PermGen is history, so nobody needs to get confused about it anymore.

Comment: @JavaPupil if the answer helped you, could you please help to mark as the accepted answer (the tick symbol beside my answer) so that we can close this question?